# SSRS Cache Report - Expiration from first or last request?

Tags: caching, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

"Cache a temporary copy of the report. Expire copy of report after a number of minutes: 5"

Does this expire after 5 minutes from the first request that generated the cached report, or after 5 minutes with no request?

For example, if a report is set to expire after 5 minutes, and I make a request every minute, do I ever get the latest data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache expiration is triggered only based on the the selected cache duration.  The cache will expire after a set amount if time from when the data was first retrieved.  It doesn't matter how many times you refresh the report. All that matters is the cache duration expiring.